# How is Raft linearlizable?

Tags: distributed, consensus, raft

I am pretty new to distributed systems and was wondering how Raft consensus algorithm is linearizable. Raft commits log entries through quorum. At the moment the leader Raft commits, this means that more than half of the participants has the replicated log. But there may be a portion of the participants that doesn't have the latest logs or that they have the logs but haven't received instructions to commit those logs.

Or does Raft's read linearizability require a read quorum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, linearizability pertains to both reads and writes, and yes, both are accomplished with a quorum. To make reads linearizable, reads must be handled by the leader, and the leader must verify it has not been superseded by a newer leader *after* applying the read to the state machine but before responding to the client. In practice, though, many real-world implementations use relaxed consistency models for reads, e.g. allowing reads from followers. But note that while quorums guarantee linearizability for the Raft cluster, that doesn’t mean client requests are linearizable. To extend linearizability to clients, sessions must be added to prevent dropped/duplicated client requests from producing multiple commits in the Raft log for a single commit, which would violate linearizabity.

Comment: I'll just put RAFT paper here: https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf.
Section 8 "Client interaction" describes  linearizable semantics (which is quite what was put in above answer). Having your attention, I'll recommend you reading whole RAFT paper, it's well written and quite understandable while being relatively short (15 pages) at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

kuujo has explained what's linearizability. I'll answer your other doubt in the question.

`But there may be a portion of the participants that don't have the latest logs or that they have the logs but haven't received instructions to commit those logs`.

This is possible after a leader commits a log entry and some of the peers do not have this log entry **right now**, but other peers will have it eventually in some ways, Raft does several things to guarantee that:

- Even if the leader has committed a log entry (*let's say LogEntry at index=8*) and answered the client, background routines are still trying to sync `logEntry:8` to other peers. If RPC fails, (*it's possible*)
- Raft sends a heartbeat periodically(*a kind of AppendEntries*), this heartbeat RPC will sync logs the leader has to followers if followers do not have it. After followers have `logEntry:8`, followers will compare its local commitIndex and leaderCommitIndex in the RPC args to decide if it should commit `logEntry:8`. If the leader fails immediately after committing a log, (*it's rare but possible*)
- Based on the election rule, only the one who has the `logEntry:8` can win the election. After a new leader elected, the new leader will continue using the heartBeat to sync `logEntry:8` to other peers. What happens if a follower falls behind so much that it can not get all logs from the leader? (*it happens a lot when you try to add a new node*). In this scenario, Raft will use a snapshot RPC mechanism to sync all data and trimmed logs.